# What do you call a communication in which both sides can be affected?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I am describing 'client-server-clients' architecture.
This means that all the sides can send data to each other via the server.
It is used in software that consists of PC application, server and mobile application.

So, how to say it right in this way: PC application and mobile application are ... ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few words that can describe this:

- The clients are using the server as a *communication hub*.
- The server *intermediates* communication between the clients.
- The server *routes* or *forwards* communication between the clients.
- The server is a *middleman* for all client communication.

The closest technical term I can think of that is a single word is *proxy*, but that has other distinct meanings in network communications, so you should avoid that.

Comment: thank you. And could you add a word or some of them to the end of this phrase "PC application and mobile application are ->>here<<-"

Comment: "PC application and mobile application communication occurs through the central server."

Comment: He might be looking for "duplex"?